# EntityRepository not found

Tags: php, doctrine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Doctrine error: Class 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338256/doctrine-error-class-doctrine-orm-entityrepository-not-found)

I'm new in Doctrine, I'm following the examples in the documentation. I created my entities and everything is working fine until I created a Repository. I have an entity called User and a UserRepository.

But when I try to use the User repository I get the error message: **Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\excap\repositories\UserRepository.php on line 10**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * Description of UserRepository
 *
 * @author Mario
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
```

How can I solved this?

```
<?php
//bootstrap_doctrine.php
$isDevMode = true;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__.'/entities'), $isDevMode);
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => 'mydbuser',
    'password' => 'mydbpassword',
    'dbname' => 'mydbname'
);

$entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
?>
```

---

```
<?php
//boostrap.php
//Entities
require_once 'entities/User.php';
require_once 'entities/Gender.php';
require_once 'entities/AccessPoint.php';

//Repositories
require_once 'repositories/UserRepository.php';

if(!class_exists("Doctrine\Common\Version", FALSE))
{
    require_once 'bootstrap_doctrine.php';
}
?>
```

---

```
<?php
// autoload.php generated by Composer
if (!class_exists('Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader', false)) {
    require __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/ClassLoader.php';
}

return call_user_func(function() {
    $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
    $composerDir = __DIR__ . '/composer';

    $map = require $composerDir . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
    foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
        $loader->add($namespace, $path);
    }

    $classMap = require $composerDir . '/autoload_classmap.php';
    if ($classMap) {
        $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
    }

    $loader->register();

    return $loader;
});

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The problem was in the bootstrap.php file. I was loading the entities before loading the bootstrap_doctrine.php; that's all.

Answer (score 1):

With the limited information you have given, I would venture a guess that you have a misconfigured autoloader; it doesn't appear to be able to automagically include the EntityRepository class.

Without any further information, I can't really help you other than to point you to [Doctrine's documentation on the autoloader](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html)

Comment: Thank you Craige, what other information should I post? the autoloader content?

Comment: At the least, we would need to see the autoloader/bootstrap files. It also wouldn't hurt to see the file instantiating the UserRepository.

Comment: At list in the documentation says: Autoloading is taken care of by Composer. You just have to include the composer autoload file in your project:

<?php
// Include Composer Autoload
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

Comment: But ARE you using Composer, or did you download Doctrine manually?

Comment: I downloaded it using Composer. I edited my post and added what you said. thanks a lot